# Server not reflecting code updates (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

I used DigitalOcean's one click app for Rails (shown here: https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/ruby-on-rails).

After getting the app running, I hit an error with an api call and I realized I forgot to add my .env variables.

After updating the code to fix this, I found that none of my code updates are being reflected in the live site (I've also tried commenting out and changing aspects of api responses, also logging and printing (no changes have shown up).

I've tried the following commands in various combinations to no effect:

```
rails restart
systemctl restart rails.service
systemctl daemon-reload
service nginx restart
```

My app's specs:

Rails 5.2
Ruby 2.4
puma 3.11

Comment: Have you killed puma?

Comment: @DennyMueller No, and actually this was the solution. I solved it by running `kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)` I have a hunch this isn't best practices though...

Comment: According to https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/restart.md it is more or less. You could also try `pumactl --control-url 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9293' --control-token foo restart`. Change the localhost and port to your setup.